# ¿Añadir página 404?

Tags: html, servidor, appserv

Estoy trabajando en una página, dónde he colocado una sub-página del directorio raíz/404, dentro están el archivo "index.html" y sus respectivos archivos de diseño, el problema es que al ingresar a páginas inexistentes sólo me arroja el error 404, pero no me re-direcciona a dicha página de la carpeta 404.

Leyendo encontré que en el archivo hhtpd.conf de la carpeta conf (en AppServ) tenía que cambiar la línea `#ErrorDocument 404 missing.html` por mi directorio, es decir `ErrorDocument 404 /raíz/404`, he probado con esa línea, como con `ErrorDocument 404 /raíz/404/index.html`, entre otras, pero no me re-direcciona a esa página.

¿Alguien podría ayudarme a entender bien qué archivo debo configurar o qué línea debería colocar? Gracias...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He encontrado la solución, aunque era algo muy sencillo:
Después de realizar la configuración mencionada en mi pregunta, tenía que reiniciar el servidor de Apache que viene con AppServ.

PD: Dejo la pregunta por si alguien llega a tener el mismo problema, de ser necesario no tengo problema con eliminarla.

Comment: Puedes incluso marcar tu respuesta como aceptada, da igual que la hayas escrito tú.